# IBM MQ: Is a channel for sending only necessary?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am having difficulties in understanding IBM MQ.

I would like to write a client that will only send messages to the queue. From what I have understood it looks to me that I don't need to use a channel for that scenario. My source is this book: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp0021.html

But when I try to connect to the Queue I am getting the error code

```
2540 (09EC) (RC2540): MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME
```

This is my sample code that will catch the exception with the above mentioned error code:

```
 @Test   
    public void init() throws InitializationException {
        MqConfigurationData mqConfigurationData = confManager.getUserConfig().getMqConfigurationData();
        MQEnvironment.hostname = mqConfigurationData.getHostname();
        MQEnvironment.port = new Integer(mqConfigurationData.getPort());

        try {
            MQQueueManager mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(mqConfigurationData.getQueueManager());
        } catch (MQException e) {
            throw new InitializationException(ApiExceptionId.INIT_MQ_CONFIGURATION, e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

So my question is: Do I need a channel even in a client-only scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application executes on the same server as the queue manager you want it to connect to then you **do not** need a channel to connect to, in this case the application would connect in Bindings mode using IPC.

If you want to connect over the network to the queue manager (on a different server or even the same server) then you **do** need a channel to connect to, in this case the application would connect in Client mode using TCP/IP.

See the Knowledge center page "[Using IBM MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030520_.htm)" for further details on the two modes of connection.

---

In your sample you are indicating you want to use a Client mode of connection by specifying the `MQEnvironment.hostname` and `MQEnvironment.port`.  The error `MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME` would be expected if a `SVRCONN` channel does not exist on the queue manager.  Since you are not specifying `MQEnvironment.channel` the IBM MQ classes for Java application is probably trying to connect with a NULL channel name which would not exist.

---

Please note that per the v9.0 Knowledge center page "[Using IBM MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030520_.htm)", IBM MQ Classes for Java have been functionally stabilized at the level shipped in IBM MQ Version 8.0.

> IBM will make no further enhancements to the IBM MQ classes for Java
>   and they are functionally stabilized at the level shipped in IBM MQ
>   Version 8.0.

It would be recommended to use IBM MQ Classes for JMS for a newly developed application.

Comment: Hey Josh - Thank you for the information this helped me stepping further. What if someone plans to have a local queue and use the bindings mode but development is remote? Is there any scenario or hint you can give me how to connect to such a queue without a channel - just for development purposes?

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept and our vote it up.  There is no way to remotely connect to a queue with out a SVRCONN channel.  You could download for free the MQ Advanced for Developers and create your own local queue manager to test against in binding mode.  Look at the tag info for [[tag:ibm-mq]] for the download link.